# VS .Net Core Razor pages do not update unless project is re-started

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a simple .Net Core 3.1 project in VS 2019. I edit a cshtml file in VS while the project is running (ie set a border color or add a label). Under MVC, I could refresh the browser window and the updates would be reflected. I could see the results of my changes immediately. Now I must re-start the project and navigate to my page to see the changes. Very frustrating. Is there a fix for this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft mentioned in the documentation to add runtime compilation.

> Runtime compilation may be optionally enabled by configuring your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runtime-compilation

Add **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** package.

Update **Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IMvcBuilder builder = services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    ...
```